# Lilypond: Adjacent analysis brackets

Tags: lilypond

I need several analysis bracket combinations which are rather unusual (at least I didn't find a lot help in the net). First of all I wanted overlapping analysis brackets, which I managed to achieve already. Now, what I also need is "adjacent brackets", meaning that one bracket ends on a note while on the same note another one starts. So in theory I would need this: "g4\stopGroup\startGroup". However, this results in simply one big bracket. Here is my example code, which currently has the problem that the g4 is in both voices and therefore visible twice, while it should only be there once, but both brackets should include it.

```
\version "2.19.61"

adjtwo = \relative c'' {
    s2 g4\startGroup a b c\stopGroup d e
}

adjone = \relative c' {
    \once \override HorizontalBracket #'direction = #UP
    e\startGroup f g\stopGroup
}

\score {
  \new Staff {
    <<
      \voiceOne \adjone
      \voiceThree \adjtwo
    >>
  }
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists "Horizontal_bracket_engraver"
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\version "2.19.61"

\score {
  \relative {
    \override HorizontalBracket #'direction = #UP
    e'\startGroup f g\stopGroup <>\startGroup a
    b c\stopGroup d e
  }
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists "Horizontal_bracket_engraver"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but no this is not what I want because the second bracket starts at the a while I want it to start at g (where the first one stops)

Answer (score 0):

A work around to make this, is the following:

1. put `\starGroup` and `\stopGroup` where you need. The unique condition is that you can not put a `\stopGroup` following a `\startGroup`. You have to put at least 1 note among their. You can put the `\stopGroup` after the following note, don't worry
2. fix the position and length of the bracket that are wrong drawn with `\once \override HorizontalBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-3.0 . 1.5)`.

For your example, you can do the following:

```
adjone = \relative c' {
  \once \override HorizontalBracket #'direction = #UP
  e \startGroup f g \stopGroup 
  \once \override HorizontalBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-3.0 . 1.5)
  a \startGroup b c \stopGroup d e
}


\score {
  \new Staff {
    <<
      \voiceOne \adjone
    >>
  }
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists "Horizontal_bracket_engraver"
  }
}
```

And you get this score:

(I can not put images embed yet) Here is the link of the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxXAc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is quite old, but I was looking to do the same thing, and here's how I did it:

```
        <<
        \new Voice \with {
            \consists Horizontal_bracket_engraver
            % \override HorizontalBracket.direction = #UP
            \override HorizontalBracket.side-axis = 0
            \override HorizontalBracket.Y-offset = -5
        }
        {
            \relative c' {
                c-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \startGroup
                d-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \stopGroup
                e-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "H" \startGroup
                f-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \stopGroup
                g-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \startGroup
                a-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \stopGroup
                b-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "H" \startGroup
                c-\stopGroup
                
            }
        } \\
        \new Voice \with {
            \consists Horizontal_bracket_engraver
            \override HorizontalBracket.direction = #UP
            \override HorizontalBracket.Y-offset = 3.8
        }
        {
            \relative c' {
                \hideNotes
                \override HorizontalBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-1 . 0.5)
                c
                d-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \startGroup
                e-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "H" \stopGroup
                f-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \startGroup
                g-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \stopGroup
                \override HorizontalBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-1 . -1.4)
                a-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "W" \startGroup
                b-\tweak HorizontalBracketText.text "H" \stopGroup
                c-\stopGroup
                
            }
        }
        >>
```

[image: image of lilypond output]

By having two instances of the same melody (in this case a scale) you can set one to `\hideNotes` so that only the brackets are shown. By setting a Y-offset for each set of brackets I was able to find some reasonable spacing from the staff, as well as keep the brackets lined up with each other on the Y axis. The `\override HorizontalBracket.shorten-pair` instances in the second voice helped clean up the look of the brackets so that they looked nicer against the visual of the other voice. I may even do the same for the first voice's brackets, because it could be cleaned up a little if I'm being picky. Relatedly, it occurs to me now that one may be able to keep all of the brackets on the same side of the staff if you shorten all of the brackets adequately. Worth a try!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**